# Run docker with all ports open

Tags: docker

I want to start docker but the VNC ports keep changing everytime i start docker container. So I was wondering if there is anyway to start docker image with ALL Ports OPEN?

Comment: Use the hosts network stack.   But that's using a sledgehammer for a problem the size of a pin.

Answer (score 0):

-p external port:internal port (e.g. -p 80:80) if you wanted it to map port 80 in the container to port 80 on the host O/S.  [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/usingdocker/).